# Sprite not on position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

my sprites are not on position on diffrent screen sizes. What i have to do?

My headline actor looks like:

```
package actors;

public class Headline extends Actor{

 public static final int HEADLINE_POS_X = 450;
 public static final int HEADLINE_POS_Y = 200;


 private final TextureRegion textureRegion;
 private Rectangle textureRegionBounds;
 private OrthographicCamera cam;


public Headline(TextureRegion textureRegion,OrthographicCamera cam) {
    this.textureRegion = textureRegion;
    this.cam = cam;
    Vector3 vec = new Vector3(Constants.HEADLINE_POS_X,Constants.HEADLINE_POS_Y,0);
    cam.unproject(vec);
    textureRegionBounds = new Rectangle(vec.x,vec.y , textureRegion.getRegionWidth(), textureRegion.getRegionHeight());
}

 @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(textureRegion, textureRegionBounds.x, textureRegionBounds.y,800,150);
 }
}
```

i call in in my screen class.

Comment: How you create `stage`, show that code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewport for your requirement, I supposed `APP_WIDTH` and `APP_HEIGHT` is constant.

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

  public MenuScreen(Main game) {
     ViewPort viewPort=new ExtendViewport(Constants.APP_WIDTH,Constants.APP_HEIGHT);
     this.stage = new Stage(viewPort);
     this.game = game;
     this.sb = game.sb;
     setHeadline();
  }

  private void setHeadline() {
     atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.HEADLINES_IMAGE_ATLAS_PATH));
     stage.addActor(new Headline(atlas.findRegion(Constants.MENUHEADLINE_REGION_NAMES)));
  }

  @Override
  public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
  }
}
```

HeadLine is an `Actor` having `TextureRegion`, why not you use `Image` for your requirement, if you want some extra property then extend your HeadLine with `Image` class.

```
Image image=new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
image.setPosition(100,100);   // positon fit for all device screen.
stage.addActor(image);
```

**EDIT**

```
public class Headline extends Image {

   public Headline(TextureRegion textureRegion) {
       super(textureRegion);
   }
}
```

And In `setHeadline()` method of `MenuScreen`

```
stage.addActor(new Headline(atlas.findRegion(Constants.MENUHEADLINE_REGION_NAMES)));
```

Comment: i'm implementing Actor in Headline so i cant implement Image

Comment: Why not, `Image` is also an `Actor`, having `TextureRegion` ?

Comment: But how can i draw it could i set the Headline to image and add this actor to stage?

Comment: yes, If you implement Actor then you need to write draw part by yourself but if your `Headline` is child of Image then only you need to pass drawable in constructor.

Comment: public class Headline extends Image implements Drawable and in menuscreen Image image=new Image(new Headline(atlas.findRegion(Constants.MENUHEADLINE_REGION_NAMES)));
      image.setPosition(100,100);   // positon fit for all device screen.
      stage.addActor(image);

Comment: I mean drawable by an object that can be drawn like `TextureRegion`, `NinePatch` or any `Drawable` implemented class, I've edited my answer check that