# How to make my game adapt to all android devices?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm  developing a game and I'm a beginner in Android game development. I'm using `Android Studio` and `libgdx`. I need screen to be adaptable on all devices. I am using screen width and height in my code which is changing the position and view of the game screen in different devices. How can I solve this? Can anyone help me getting this done with neat code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When dealing with different screens it is often necessary to decide
>   for a certain strategy how those different screen sizes and aspect
>   ratios should be handled. Camera and Stage support different viewport
>   strategies.

LibGDX provides a more convenient way of dealing with this problem: [Viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports)

---

`Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()` returns the width and height (in pixels) of the window (or on mobile, the screen) that your application is running in.

viewport `worldWidth/height` is the width and height of the view of the camera, in whatever unit is applicable for you.

The Viewport relates to where and how much of the game world you see, in world units. The Gdx.graphics.getWidth() is the physical pixels of the screen or window.

Comment: if i use getWidth and getHeight fo different point location to draw or sprite images, this will work? like ,will this make my screen smaller in big screen devices or go out of the screen in small screen devices?

Comment: You should use viewport instead of setting position by using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: any example? like code blocks of same issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44033078/3445320

Comment: also take look of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43731930/3445320)

Comment: thank you @Abhishek it helpmed me.thanks alot

Comment: yeah sure i do . thank you so much

Comment: @user8276616 great

Comment: http://sajidaashaz.000webhostapp.com/img1.jpg

Comment: @user8276616 what is it ?

Comment: I have shared a link.Take a look at this which i want to be in my game screen.Rects and lines are used.It should also be fitted on all screen sizes.Any idea?

Comment: the link contains the image. please have a look at that

Comment: @iamsajidshaz_aa May be my answer is wrong but I don't think so answer by Tonteria24 is write in this context ? Switching between accept and unaccept may block your account. Best of Luck for your future :D

Comment: Sorry it was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

You should use dp units to size the elements in the screen

Then multipling the dp with the screen density you will get screen pixels.
To obtain the screen density do :

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: could you please show mr this in a rough  code blocks?

Comment: and thank you for your time in replying to my question

Comment: `getResources()` is method of `ContextThemeWrapper` class of android, I think no use in LibGDX